# How to use INTUIT payment gateway for a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, payment, intuit-partner-platform

I am working on a asp.net mvc5 application. How can I integrate INTUIT payment gateway there? Looking for pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on Intuit Payments can be found at
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0010_hosted_paypage

To get started, please follow the quick start guide at
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/030_qbms/0030_get_set_up

When you are creating an app, please make sure to use the correct system and URL's.

If you are creating a production application, make sure you do NOT include the "ptc/" shown in the examples.